# Unix distros Ubuntu and Debian on Window 10

Tags: debian, ubuntu, windows

I am running Windows 10 on my computer and I recently installed Debian 10 on it from Microsoft store, but now I want to also run Ubuntu on the same Computer (for practical purpose) and I want to know if it is possible to have Debian and Ubuntu running on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

You are running Debian 10 using the **Windows Subsystem for Linux**. Yes, you can also have Ubuntu running on the same computer. Just install Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store just like you did for Debian.

(You need to make sure you have enough disk space available)

Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config for more info.